# Boot problem with 19.10

Tags: boot, 19.10

I just upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 and I'm having a boot problem. When I turn it on I get the Ubuntu logo and the dots moving, and that all it does stays on the logo. I have to manually turn it off and on three or four times before it boots up properly. Is there a command line too fix this problem?

I found the problem. One of my ext. drives have and old version of Ubuntu 17.10 on it. I disconnected it and it booted properly.

Comment: Press the ESC key and you should see the logs, take a close-up photo of your screen only showing the logs and edit your post to include the photo so we can see what the logs are showing.

Comment: @George I'm glad you found the solution--I recommend [posting it as an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).